# How do I switch to Condensed List view using Trello on iPad?

Tags: trello, ipad

Using Trello on an iPad.  Obviously "Q" is the shortcut to display the cards in Condensed List view, but how do I access "Q" on an iPad?  The only way to get the keyboard to display is if I am editing a card, and then (of course) "Q" is just typed in the text box.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently a way to access the condensed mode, other than hitting <kbd>q</kbd>

Trello [plans to have a card filtering UI](https://trello.com/card/board/card-filtering/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e7224d1ba71ca0000044974), which includes the ability to show only cards assigned to you, or which have a specified combination of labels.  This UI will be iPad friendly.